# Relation between two polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ when one polynomial cuts the graph of another .

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, curves

This question occurred to me from an earlier question I had asked (Use of calculus in finding relations between roots of polynomial equations of degree greater than or equal to
2.)

Now , if the curve $p(x)=ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$ is cut by a line at four distinct points , then the $x$-coordinates of the intersection points are the roots of my original function $p(x)$. From this,  is it true that for any polynomial $q(x)$ with degree $n$, when cut by another curve $f(x)$ of degree not greater than $n-2$, the $x$-coordinates of the intersection points are the roots of my original function $q(x)$? And if it is,  then can I just apply the sum of roots property to calculate the sum of these $x$-coordinates?

Comment: wrong. The $x$ coordinates of your four points are roots of $p(x) - fx -g \; , \; \;$  where your line is $y = fx+g$

Comment: @ Will Jagy Sure.  I just told that they will be the roots of p(x) itself to point out that similarity.

Comment: Only the sum of roots and sum of product of roots taken two at a time will be same (by Vieta's relations), the two polynomials are different so they naturally have different roots as well